# How to Resolve High Datagram Received Address Errors on Windows with Intel UDP Unicast?

Tags: windows, networking, cpu-usage, rtp, datagram

**How to Resolve High Datagram Received Address Errors on Windows with Intel UDP Unicast?

High CPU Usage and Datagram Received Errors in RTP Unicast UDP Transmission on Windows**

Hello,

I am sending data to a Windows PC using RTP (Real-time Transport Protocol) Unicast UDP. However, the receiving computer experiences high CPU usage and freezing issues during data reception, specifically related to System Interrupts. When another application that communicates via UDP multicast is running, this becomes an issue. When the data is received in response to the RTP transmission, there are no such issues, but if the data is not received, the CPU usage increases.

I have monitored the situation using the Performance Monitor and noticed an increase in the Datagram Received Errors value.

I have tried this scenario on several different PCs, and the same results persist.

I would greatly appreciate your suggestions and solutions regarding this issue. If you could provide any possible steps to troubleshoot or identify the root cause, it would be of immense help.

Thank you in advance!

```
|Fail           |Fail           |Fail           |Ok         |Ok
|i7-9850HL  |i5-10400F  |i7-11800H  |i3-7100T   |i7-6500U
|Windows 10 |Windows 10 |Windows 10 |Windows 10 |Windows 10
```

the CPU usage increased, and there were freezing issues. There are Datagram Received Errors